# MakeFile without Xcode on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Is there an alternative to use "make" to make a file without using Xcode on Mac? Xcode is huge and normally requires the latest software installed and I want to keep my OSX 10.8.5 installation intact.

Comment: What the heck do you want to do?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need/want Xcode, you can simply get `make` and other command line tools without Xcode by downloading the [Command Line Tools package here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-). You need to sign in with an Apple ID first.

Comment: you are right... totally works. Just login and download the Command Line Tools for your OSX version and you will have the "make" command available to you on the terminal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked all over and the best way is to install Xcode. Below is a link on how to enable this feature once Xcode is installed.

[Enable "Command Line Tools" on Xcode](http://satishgandham.com/2012/04/make-command-not-found-in-mac-osx/)

Comment: By the way, if you are using an older version than OSX 10.10 as of 12/04/2015, you will not be able to install Xcode since that version is required. No way around it - sad.